# Use CPU fallback if OpenCV's Cuda extensions are not available

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

In my code I'm trying to capitalize the power of a possibly present cuda capable GPU. While this code works well on computers that have cuda available (and where OpenCV was compiled with cuda support), I have troubles implementing a *fallback* to CPU. Even building fails, since the imports I'm using

```
#include "opencv2/core/cuda.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp"
```

are not found. I'm quite a novice regarding C++ program architecture. How would I need to model my code to support such a fallback functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are implementing a fallback you probably want to switch to it at runtime. But the fact that you are getting compiler error messages suggests that you are compiling with different flags. In general, you probably want something like this:

```
if (HasCuda()) {
  RunCudaCode(...);
} else {
  RunCpuCode(...);
}
```

Alternatively, you could build two shared libraries one with and one without Cuda and load the one that you need based on `HasCuda()`. However, that approach only makes sense if your binary is huge and you're running into memory issues.

It might be necessary to have a similar block in your startup code that initializes Cuda.